# Calculating formulae in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, formula

I would like to insert a calculation in Excel using Python.
Generally it can be done by inserting a formula string into the relevant cell.
However, if i need to calculate a formula multiple times for the whole column
the formula must be updated for each individual cell. For example, if i need to 
calculate the sum of two cells, then for cell C(k) the computation would be A(k)+B(k).
In excel it is possible to calculate C1=A1+B1 and then automatically expand the 
calculation by dragging the mouse from C1 downwards.
My question is: Is it possible to the same thing with Python, i.e. to define a formula in only one cell and then to use Excel capabilities to extend the calculation for the whole column/row?

Thank you in advance,
Sasha

Comment: Some sample code would be useful.  What module are you using?  what os are you on?

Comment: I work with windows, excel 2003, some package called easyExcel - it is just a number of useful functions implemented with COM

Answer (score 3):

As [Roberto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116725/calculating-formulae-in-excel-with-python/1116782#1116782)  mentions, you can use **[xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt)** and a trusty for-loop:

```
import xlwt

w = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('mysheet')

for i in range(10):
    ws.write(i, 0, i)
    ws.write(i, 1, i+1)
    ws.write(i, 2, xlwt.Formula("$A$%d+$B$%d" % (i+1, i+1)))

w.save('myworkbook.xls')
```

Comment: Of course it is possible to that, but my question was how to do it using AutoFill capability of Excel...

Comment: `def _num_to_let(num):
    if num > 25:
        return _num_to_let(num/26-1) + chr(97+ num % 26)
    return chr(97+num)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using COM bindings, then you can simply record a macro in Excel, then translate it into Python code.
If you are using xlwt, you have to resort to normal loops in python..

Comment: I am using COM, recorded macro, but I don't know how to translate
the following:




ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-7]/RC[-10]*R[-1]C"
Range("M6").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M6:M592")
Range("M6:M592").Select

Answer (score 0):

Sasha,

Python code translated from your macro would look like this:

```
startCell = mySheet.Range("M6")
wholeRange = mySheet.Range("M6:M592")
startCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-7]/RC[-10]*R[-1]C"
startCell.AutoFill(Destination=wholeRange)
```

Haven't tested it, but I write this often at work.  Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Greg: please edit your response so that the code shows up as 4 lines not 1 line ... hint: start each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I did...  OK, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate in the horizontal direction, here is a function I use.  0 -> a,  26 -> aa, 723 -> aav

```
def _num_to_let(num):
        if num > 25:
            return _num_to_let(num/26-1) + chr(97+ num % 26)
        return chr(97+num)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate in xlwt for columns (in formulas) you can use Utils module from xlwt like this:

```
from xlwt import Utils
print Utils.rowcol_pair_to_cellrange(2,2,12,2)
print Utils.rowcol_to_cell(13,2)
>>>
C3:C13
C14
```

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the COM wrapping libraries will allow you to use a User Defined Functions written in Python. This is the domain of [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) and [PyXll](https://www.pyxll.com/).

[FlyingKoala](https://flyingkoala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worked_example_horticulture.html) also does this as it's an extension of xlwings. FlyingKoala has added ability to (on-the-fly) read Excel functions and convert them into Python code and evaluate the equation in Python.